# Trying to find the name of this patience-style game

Tags: identify-this-game

I was taught this two-pack version of patience a few years ago and want to know if it has an official name or not.

Two packs are shuffled together. 8 columns of 8 rows of cards are layed out face up on the table- 64 cards in total. The rest of the cards are faced down to the side of the table and turned over one at a time.

Any card may be placed on any other card with a value one above it (ie. Any 3 can be played on any 4 etc) but only if they are the same suit can cards be moved in groups. The only cards that can be placed on an empty column is one of the kings.

The aim is to clear the table into 8 stacks from ace to king above the table like in 'traditional' solitaire games.

Does anyone know if it has an official name?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a 2-deck variation of the game, 'Golf'. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(patience)) page lists it as a starting with a 7 x 5 card layout. This [website](http://www.golfsolitaire.net/TwoDeckGolfSolitaire.html) has a 2-deck version, which starts with a 9 x 7 card layout.

More rules or game play example might help to narrow it down.

Comment: No, it's not the game Golf, since the movement of card don't work like described.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through my copy of "The complete patience book" - an old tome indeed, the nearest I can see is "Persian", sometimes called "Bezique" which plays as you've said but using a deck without 6s,5s,4s,3s and 2s.

Comment: "*tomb*" or "*tome*"? The former is where one buries rich people; the latter an old large book.

Answer (score 1):

Spider Solitaire? It's a pre-loaded game on Windows.... I could be wrong but it sounds exactly the same. Check your PC games and try it.

Note that in the PC version you can select whether to play with all 4 suits or just one or two.

Comment: Spider is not on a 8 x 8 grid...

Comment: Well, it's not the Spider Solitaire game, since it's not dealt with all cards faced up. It normally also uses more the 8 columns of cards.

Answer (score -2):

This game is named Martin in our game BVS Solitaire Collection: https://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/martin.htm

Comment: Please read our guidance on [self promotion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), consider editing this and raise a moderator flag and this can be undeleted.  It appears to be the right answer.  Thanks!